# Json stringify then parse from URL

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, url

I seem to be having an issue in stringify'ing then pasing from a url object

I simply stringify my object and set the location (with angulars $location) like so

```
 currentUrl = {"module1" : {"is" : true} }
 $location.search(JSON.stringify(currentUrl));
```

So this parses to the url just fine, however when I try to grab it from the url i get this back

```
     console.log($location.search());
      ---
     Object {{"module1":{"is":true}}: true}
```

How do I parse this back into an object so I can use it? If I do

```
 JSON.parse($location.search());
```

I get a syntax error. I maybe because of how search returns the object? I am a bit confused here, could use some help. Thanks!

So I put it in the url with

```
   $location.search(JSON.stringify(currentUrl));
```

What are the steps I need to take to get it back into this form :

```
 {"module1" : {"is" : true} }
```

Edit -

It just appears it's setting the json object as the key in the location like

```
 { "mystrigifiedobject": true }
```

Edit2 :

based off the first edit, I was able to solve it (assming it's set in the locations object key) like so  :

```
  currentUrl = $location.search();
                    currentUrl = JSON.parse(Object.keys(currentUrl));
                    console.log(currentUrl);
```

This just feels a little weird though, am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @DanielA.White could you get me an example? I'm unsure - it's a little weird but im not using routes for this, the general idea is sending saving an object in the url and being able to access it - does routeparams do that?

Comment: When serializing an object to JSON for a url, don't forget to run the result through encodeURIComponent() e.g.: 

$location.search(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(currentUrl)));

Comment: Also, $location.search() returns an Object, not a JSON string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$location.search() returns the parsed search items from the url path as an object. This means this kind of url:

`?a=b&c=d`

will result in this object:

`{ a: 'b', c: 'd' }`

When you call this function:

```
currentUrl = {"module1" : {"is" : true} }
 $location.search(JSON.stringify(currentUrl));
```

your path will look like this:

`?%7B%22module1%22:%7B%22is%22:true%7D%7D`

and the parsed object returned from `$location.search` will look like this:

`{{"module1":{"is":true}}: true}`

not that this is an object with one entry and the key is your JSON

So what you need to do in order to get your object back is this:

```
var parsedObject = $location.search();
var yourObject = JSON.parse(Object.keys(parsedObject)[0]);
```

see this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HB7LU/11633/

But please note: you should encode your string when putting it in a url:

```
$location.search(encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(currentUrl)));
```

Answer (score 0):

`$routeParams` provides access to both routing template values and query string values (as a string).

```
function ctrl($routeParams) {
    var yourValueAsString = $routeParams.yourKey;
}

function ctrl2($location) {
    $location.search('yourKey', JSON.stringify(...));
}
```

A better alternative would be to switch to using the UI Router which deals with this better.

Comment: I am not using ng-routes for this, the routing is done through something else.